# My whatsapp says im offline, and will not let me access it

Tags: offline

I have gone on to my Whatsapp but all of a sudden my chats and messages are not showing up. I looked in settings and tapped on all the options, i went on privacy settings and it says 'you can not change privacy settings when you are offline' how do i get back online? Thank you in advanced :) (I've rebooted my phone multiple times)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your internet connection is working. If it's okay then try to **Reset** the Whatsapp app like this -

> Menu>Application Manager>Downloaded apps>Whatsapp>Clear data (Clear
>   cache)

.
Now you've to reactivate your Whatsapp account which takes not more than a minute. This should work for sure. Comment if problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reinstalling it. I do had this issue once, and after reinstalling it just worked.